# When I shut down Linux Mint on VMware, it erases everything

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, linux-mint, vmware

I have installed Linux Mint on VMware from Windows 10 Pro. Every time i connect to Linux, it erases everything i have done the las time i logged in. Software, files, everything!

Why is this happening?

**EDIT** :
Here is the `sudo df` that a user asked. (@AFH)

[image: (I couldnt copy/paste from VM, so here are 2 screenshots.)]

[image: Screenshot no.2]

Comment: Have you installed a Live Boot?

Comment: Ummm. . No. What is that?

Comment: It's a working OS with a memory-resident file system, normally booted from USB disc or DVD, and used to install a resident OS. Surely you used this for your VMware installation?

Comment: Yes. I think. But i have installed many more OS's and have done the same installation. But every other OS is storing the files correct.

Comment: Please run `sudo df` from the booted system and post the result in your question.

Comment: @AFH  Ok. Will do it.

Comment: Did you create the VM yourself?  Is the VM configured to revert to a snapshot every time it's powered off?

Comment: @jamesdlin I dont know about it... But yes, i created myself.

Comment: @AFH Ok. Here is the ` sudo df `.

Comment: You’re running a Live system. Nothing you do there is persistent. Are you *sure* you installed it? What happens when you boot the VM without the Mind CD/DVD image?

Comment: @DanielB says what I have been trying to establish. I have just started Ubuntu Live (also Debian-derived) in VMware, but it uses an `overlay` file system for `/`, which I cannot reconcile with your system's `aufs`. As Kamil Maciorowski's answer says, the output of `mount` may verify this. Booting Ubuntu Live gives the option of **Install** or **Try**: if you choose **Try**, as I did for my tests, disc changes are saved in a memory overlay to the file system on the read-only boot device. I am pretty sure this is happening to you, but I cannot verify without your install disc to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

`aufs` mounted as `/` is a [union mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount). It uses a static content (probably mounted to `/rofs` beforehand) at first, then any change you do to the filesystem is transparently laid over it.

These changes are kept in RAM (we could see details if you posted the output of `mount`) and they are lost every time you reboot the (virtual) machine.

This or equivalent solution is often used by live boot OS-es or Linux installers (that allow you to try the OS before you install); it's uncommon on regular desktops. I don't know Mint enough to tell how you got into this situation and what you should have done differently.

Answer (score 0):

I also confronted the issue.
When you open the version of Mint, you need to click on 'Install Linux Mint' icon on the desktop.
Hope this helps!